# Hibernate multiple queries executed for many to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are facing some strange issue while handling the one to many relationships. To describe in detail we have below entities,

RCAAssessmentUnit :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RCAAssessmentUnit")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class RCAAssessmentUnit extends AbstractPersistentEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3114793801627752533L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document", nullable = true)
    protected Document document;

    @Column(name = "Name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rca_assessment_unit_admin", nullable = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    protected RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin rcaAssessmentUnitAdmin;
```

RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin extends AbstractPersistentEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8890257035008399346L;

    // Name
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "changed$")
    protected Date changed;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rcaAssessmentUnitAdmin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    protected List<RCAAssessmentUnit> rcaAssessmentUnits;
```

BCDocument which extends Document and maintains the inheritance joined strategy.

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "Document")
@Table(name = "BCDocument")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class BCDocument extends Document 
------
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy(value = "name")
    private List<RCAAssessmentUnit> rcaAssessmentUnits ;
```

Document :-

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "Document", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "Id" }) })
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Document extends AbstractPersistentEntity {
```

So with these relationships, we have a admin module to add/remove/edit the 'RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin'. The main page first list out all the admins and as soon as we try to edit any admin which is added in any BCDcouments from the query log we could see that multiple queries are fetched to load all the documents which extends the 'Document' entity like AWT,CTT etc. along with 
BCDocument
e.g.

```
Hibernate: select rcaassessm0_.rca_assessment_unit_admin as ------ from RCAAssessmentUnit rcaassessm0_ where rcaassessm0_.rca_assessment_unit_admin in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select document0_.Id$ as Id1_48_0_, -----
from Document document0_ left outer join AWT document0_1_ on document0_.Id$=document0_1_.Document left outer join CTT document0_2_ on document0_.Id$=document0_2_.Document left outer join WCR document0_3_ on document0_.Id$=document0_3_.Document left outer join BRST document0_4_ on document0_.Id$=document0_4_.Document left outer join BCDocument document0_5_ on document0_.Id$=document0_5_.Document left outer join Impact_Analysis_RTO impactanal1_ on document0_.Impact_Analysis_Rto=impactanal1_.Id$ where document0_.Id$ in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

So the very first operation (listing all the admins) does keep all the relationships 'Lazy' but as soon as we try to edit 'admin' why it is trying to query on the 'Document' hierarchy (as seen in second query) ? We don't need document relationships or the child objects of 'admin' while editing it. Also if 'admin' is deleted we are marking the reference of all children(RCAAssessmentUnit) to null as we don't want to delete the childs which are already added in BCDocument.

I have been reading all the related q&a on this and also checked the N+1 issue but so far unable to figure out the issue here. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**Updated:**
Below is the code block which fetch the list of Admins. Both these methods are part of backing bean which is seam component with session scope.

```
  public void retrieve() {
        TypedQuery<RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin> query = entityManager.createQuery("from RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin order by name", RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin.class);
        rcaAssessmentUnitItems = query.getResultList();
    }
```

And we have Richfaces datatable which binds this list, and on edit action the call is handled by below. So even before the control enters in this edit method , in the backend console I could see all the queries getting executed.

```
public void edit(RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin unitAdmin) {
    log.info("edit: " + unitAdmin);
RCAAssessmentUnitAdminScreen dialog = Util.getSeamComponent (RCAAssessmentUnitAdminScreen.class, true);
    dialog.setupDialog(unitAdmin, rcaAssessmentUnitItems);
```

}

```
    <rich:dataTable id="items" style="word-break: keep-all;" value="#{rcaAssessmentUnitItems}" var="row" rowKeyVar="rowKey" columnClasses="col" rowClasses="odd_row, even_row">
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <h:outputText value="No RCA Assessment Units Found" rendered="rcaAssessmentUnitItems == null or rcaAssessmentUnitItems.size == 0}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <rich:column style="text-align: center; width: 70px;">
                            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#" /></f:facet>
                        <div style="width:45px !important;margin: 0 auto !important;">
                            <a:commandButton execute="@this"  action="#{updateRCAAssessmentUnits.edit(row)}" styleClass="listItemBtn" value="#{rowKey + 1}"/>
                        </div>
                    </rich:column>
-----
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that causes the query to be executed (controller, service method, repository)?

Comment: Try to use JPA Named Entity Graph. It may help in some situations where you need or don't need to load child collections https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/

Comment: Umm... when you call `log.info()`, `RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin.toString()` will be called. Does `RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin.toString()` reference `RCAAssessmentUnitAdmin.rcaAssessmentUnits` by any chance? Could `dialog.setupDialog` possibly be referencing it somehow?

Comment: crizzis, you saved me!...although after commenting the logger the behaviour was same but the toString method was referencing the document. Also the RCAAssessmentUnit was referencing to 'Document' (it should be BCDocument) which was causing select on all Document hierarchy. Thanks a ton to get my attention on toString method.